# Issues with running Elastic in Bitbucket piplines

Tags: python, elasticsearch, cicd, bitbucket-pipelines

Hi can anyone help me debug an issue with Elastic in my CI/CD environment?

Elastic is running locally (for development) and on their managed SaaS platform for staging and production.

I have the following step in bitbucket pipelines

```
    - step: &unit_tests
    image: python:3.9
    name: Testing
    caches:
      - pip
    script:
      - pip install -r requirements.txt
      - export GC_API_DB_PORT=5432
      - export CS_DEPLOYMENT=development
      - docker run -d -p 9200:9200 -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.6.2
      - python manage.py search_index --rebuild -f
      - python -m pytest --cov-report term --cov=gc_api --cov=gc_api_auth --cov-fail-under=85
    services:
      - postgres
      - docker
```

However it seems I cannot connect to the elastic instance (I've also tried a configuration where elastic runs separately)

```
    elasticsearch:
  image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.6.2
  container_name: elasticsearch
  cap_add:
    - IPC_LOCK
  volumes:
    - elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
  ports:
    - 9200:9200
    - 9300:9300
....
    - step: &unit_tests
        image: python:3.9
        name: Testing
        caches:
          - pip
        script:
          - pip install -r requirements.txt
          - export GC_API_DB_PORT=5432
          - export ELASTIC_SEARCH_HOST=$BITBUCKET_DOCKER_HOST_INTERNAL
          - python -m pytest --cov-report term --cov=gc_api --cov=gc_api_auth --cov-fail-under=85
        services:
          - postgres
          - elasticsearch
```

Here is my error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 787, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 550, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 769, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 449, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 444, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1377, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 320, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 289, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_requests.py", line 166, in perform_request
    response = self.session.send(prepared_request, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_elasticsearch_dsl/management/commands/search_index.py", line 301, in handle
    for index in self.es_conn.indices.get_alias().values():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 347, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, headers=headers, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/indices.py", line 642, in get_alias
    return self.transport.perform_request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 417, in perform_request
    self._do_verify_elasticsearch(headers=headers, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 606, in _do_verify_elasticsearch
    raise error
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 569, in _do_verify_elasticsearch
    _, info_headers, info_response = conn.perform_request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_requests.py", line 194, in perform_request
    raise ConnectionError("N/A", str(e), e)
elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionError: ConnectionError(('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))) caused by: ConnectionError(('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response')))
```

Any input you have would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you are manually starting and detaching the docker container consider adding a sleep so as to wait for the process in the container to actually accept connections

```bash
docker run -d -p 9200:9200 docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch
sleep 10 ?
python -m pytest
```

---

If you go for the service, just note you are pasting a docker-compose service fragment in a bitbucket-pipelines.yml. While the service section has some resemblance, it is a totally different application and that definition is not valid. Check https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/databases-and-service-containers/ but all those `ports`, `valumes` and `cap_add` attributes will be, at best, ignored. Maybe it would be better if Bitbcucket Pipelines just failed due to yml invalidity because this is recurring confusion.

Now, Bitbucket Pipelines services will share the network with the agent running the script. I don't know what value you expect that "BITBUCKET_DOCKER_HOST_INTERNAL" variable to eval but it doesn't exist, check https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/variables-and-secrets/. If it is a user-defined variable, note it is unconventional and confusing to use that prefix, usually reserved for an existing application with documented variables.

Anyway: you should simply be using `localhost`.

```yaml
definitions:
  services:
    elasticsearch:
      image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch
      variables:
        "discovery.type": single-node
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
      services: [elasticsearch]
      script:
        - pip install -r requirements.txt
        - export ELASTIC_SEARCH_HOST=localhost
        - python -m pytest
```

The `pip install` instruction should be slow enough so that the elasticsearch service is ready when the test suite starts running so no `sleep` instruction should be necessary here.

---

There is yet another approach using test containers https://testcontainers-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/elasticsearch/. AFAIU the library already takes good care to block execution until the service is truly ready.

The downsides are

- you should add this as a session fixture in your pytest configuration
- this adds significant setup overhead because test-containers can't be reused among subsequent executions (watch https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-python/issues/109)

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough answer. In the meantime I've found a solution, but yours seems much cleaner. 
The problem is, you solution is not working for me. The URL is still not found:

`E           requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9200): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fb66ee317f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))`

Comment: The variables for elasticsearch won't be accpeted with that `.` and the error is as follows:

"There is an error in your bitbucket-pipelines.yml at [definitions > services > elasticsearch]. The variable name "discovery.type" is invalid. It should contain only alphanumeric characters and underscores and it should not begin with a number."

Comment: That was valid YAML but I guess Bitbucket is picky. Can you try quoting the var name? `"discovery.type": single-node`